# PHP / MYSQL Split XLS based on Column and Insert

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, xls

I have a large excel file of ship locations for the next 2 years.  Currently, I am manually splitting this file into multiple files and then importing into MYSQL.  This wont work for long though, as the Excel file gets updated everyday and needs an easier way to be imported.

The data doesnt start till row 10, Column D, and goes till Column I, then another Ship starts on Row 10 Column J to O, ect, for 22 ships. (Row 10 being the header titles)

Is there a way to automate this?  I have done some research and found I probably need to convert the XLS to CSV which isnt a problem, but I havnt found a way to state Row 10 Column's D-I into Table1, Column J to O to Table2, Column's P-U to Table3, ect.

Can someone point me in the right direction or provide some assistance.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: How much control do you have over the structure of the Excel file?  Can you use VBA to connect Excel to MySQL programatically?  What other languages/tools are available to you?

Comment: I have Visual Studio, Not very good with it though.  The structure of the file can be changed, but I download it from a remote site, and would like to just upload it to my site and let the website do the rest.  If there is a way to do it with VBA I would be interested as well.

Comment: If you download it from a remote site, one presumes that you have *no* control over its structure?  Or do you upload the file to said site?

Comment: I download it from the companies Intranet, and I upload it to Internet.  I can modify the file as needed before the file is uploaded to the Internet if needed.  The goal is to take this from an hour long task to a 2 minute task.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell not knowing all the details but I would propose the following flow:

1. Save your file as CVS (can be automated via VBA, PowerShell...)
2. Load it **as it is** in a staging table using `LOAD DATA INFILE`
3. If necessary validate, clean, normalize the data in the staging table
4. Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to copy data to factual tables (selecting only necessary columns e.g. from J to O...)
5. Truncate the staging table

If the rules of data extraction are deterministic steps 2-5 can wrapped in a stored procedure.